# What is Push Initiator application URL field in BB6 application

Tags: blackberry, browser, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to enable BB push service in my PushDemo code i had taken from the BB sample code. But the Content provider URL is empty in the demo code .

They are saying, If you use the BlackBerry Internet Service as the PPG, in the Push Initiator application URL field, type https://{server_address}/high-level-sample or https://{server_address}/low-level-sample.

I didn't get what this URL is and what that "high-level-sample" or "low-level-sample" means.

How can i do this ?

Comment: check my blog http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/search/label/Push%20Notification

Comment: Thankyou http://stackoverflow.com/users/896391/signare for your help . Let me check it . :)